# Does https encrypt URLs, too?

Tags: networking, encryption, url, https, protocol

This is fairly easy.

If I go to `https://webserver.com/someurl?a=b`, will the `someurl?a=b` part be protected, or just the contents of the site?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The entire URL will be encrypted.  When the web browser connects to the server, it connects to the appropriate IP address, starts encryption, and then sends the request (hostname, URL, parameters, form contents, etc.).

Note that the DNS lookup will *not* be encrypted, so anyone looking at your traffic can tell that you looked the domain up, even if they can't tell what you sent or what came back.  This may or may not be important in your case.

Comment: very good point that (typical / not DNSSEC) DNS lookup is unencrypted. If the hostname ends with `hub.com` but doesn't start with `git` then you might be embarassed at some point

Answer (score 8):

The entire HTTP request is encrypted. This is why having more than one SSL site per IP address is troublesome.

Comment: Can you please elaborate further your answer (explaining why and or what you meant by *troublesome*)?